# SVM provided a bad result in my data. How to fix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, linear-regression

I have a dataset that contains `510` samples for training and `127` samples for testing, each sample has `7680` features. I want to design a model to predict the height (cm)-label-from the training data. Currently, I used SVM but it provided very bad result. Could you look at my code and give me some comments. You can try it in your machine using the [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/io7vt5hi4tgwudv/AAAFnSauDUlgR3Y4He67QHbGa?dl=0) and a runnable code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Training Data
train_X = np.loadtxt('trainX.txt') # 510 x 7680
train_Y = np.loadtxt('trainY.txt') # 510 x 1
test_X = np.loadtxt('testX.txt')   # 127 x 7680
test_Y = np.loadtxt('testY.txt')   # 127 x 1

my_svr = SVR(C=1000, epsilon=0.2)
my_svr.fit(train_X,train_Y)

p_regression = my_svr.predict(test_X)
print (p_regression)
print (test_Y)
```

Some results:

**p_regression**

```
[15.67367165 16.35094166 13.10510262 14.03943211 12.7116549  11.45071423
 13.27225207  9.44959181 10.45775627 13.23953143 14.95568324 11.35994414
 10.69531821 12.42556347 14.54712287 12.25965911  9.04101931 14.03604126
 12.41237627 13.51951317 10.36302674  9.86389635 11.41448842 15.67146184
 14.74764672 11.22794536 12.04429175 12.48199183 14.29790809 16.21724184
 10.94478135  9.68210872 14.8663311   8.62974573 15.17281425 12.97230127
  9.46515876 16.24388177 10.35742683 15.65336366 11.04652502 16.35094166
 14.03943211 10.29066405 13.27225207  9.44959181 10.45775627 13.23953143
 14.95568324 11.35994414 10.69531821 12.42556347 14.54712287 12.25965911
  9.04101931 14.03604126 12.41237627 13.51951317 10.36302674  9.86389635
 11.41448842 15.67146184 14.74764672 11.22794536 12.04429175 12.48199183
 14.29790809 16.21724184 10.94478135  9.68210872 14.8663311   8.62974573
 15.17281425 12.97230127  9.46515876 16.24388177 10.35742683 15.65336366
 11.04652502 16.35094166 14.03943211 10.29066405 13.27225207  9.44959181
 10.45775627 13.23953143 14.95568324 11.35994414 10.69531821 12.42556347
 14.54712287 12.25965911  9.04101931 14.03604126 12.41237627 13.51951317
 10.36302674  9.86389635 11.41448842 15.67146184 14.74764672 11.22794536
 12.04429175 12.48199183 14.29790809 16.21724184 10.94478135  9.68210872
 14.8663311   8.62974573 15.17281425 12.97230127  9.46515876 16.24388177
 10.35742683 15.65336366 11.04652502 16.35094166 14.03943211 10.29066405
 13.27225207  9.44959181 10.45775627 13.23953143 14.95568324 11.35994414
 10.69531821]
```

**test_Y**

```
[13. 14. 13. 15. 15. 17. 13. 17. 16. 12. 17.  6.  4.  3.  4.  6.  6.  8.
  9. 18.  3.  6.  4.  6.  7.  8. 11. 11. 13. 12. 12. 14. 13. 12. 15. 15.
 16. 15. 17. 18. 17. 14. 15. 17. 13. 17. 16. 12. 17.  6.  4.  3.  4.  6.
  6.  8.  9. 18.  3.  6.  4.  6.  7.  8. 11. 11. 13. 12. 12. 14. 13. 12.
 15. 15. 16. 15. 17. 18. 17. 14. 15. 17. 13. 17. 16. 12. 17.  6.  4.  3.
  4.  6.  6.  8.  9. 18.  3.  6.  4.  6.  7.  8. 11. 11. 13. 12. 12. 14.
 13. 12. 15. 15. 16. 15. 17. 18. 17. 14. 15. 17. 13. 17. 16. 12. 17.  6.
  4.]
```

Comment: The most likely reason is that you only a train a single SVM model without doing any type of hyper-parameter optimization. It just happens that those specific hyper-parameter values are not good for those data. Of course, it can always be the case that the outcome can't be predicted using those predictor variables.

Comment: @George: Thanks. But I have tried some hyper-parameter setting and it does not provide good results. Do you think we can use other methods, instead of SVM for my task? Which method do you prefer?

Comment: A good initial starting point is to use random forests (with default parameters, but I would use ~500-1000 trees in general). They are much easier to tune than SVM and typically perform good enough. I did do that, but can't seem to get good results; I get a MSE of 21.7. What is interesting though is that on the training set, I get an out-of-bag MSE of 5.2. This suggests there is something "wrong" with the test set. Probably, the test data distribution is very different from the training data. To test that, I created new train/test data and run the model. This time I got a MSE of ~5.1.

Comment: Great to hear that. Could you please share your code?

Comment: @George, how did you manage to get MSE of ~5.1?

Comment: I merged the training and test sets and split them again using a 510/127 sample split. Doing this and running a random forest with default parameters I got 5.1. I tried with a different random split  and got ~5.7, so maybe I just got lucky there. A question to @Jame: Did you perform any type of preprocessing on the training data? Did you by any chance perform feature selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a similar approach. We will split data sets into `train` and `test` ones. `train` data set will be used for tuning hyperparameters and for fitting different models. Then we will choose the best (in terms of MSE) model and predict values from the `test` data set.

All trained (fitted) models will be saved as Pickle files, so they can be loaded later on using `joblib.load()` method.

**Output:**

```
----------------------------- [SVR_rbf] ------------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 12 fits
---------------------------- [SVR_linear] ----------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 12 fits
------------------------------ [Ridge] -------------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 7 candidates, totalling 21 fits
------------------------------ [Lasso] -------------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 18 fits
--------------------------- [RandomForest] ---------------------------
Fitting 3 folds for each of 3 candidates, totalling 9 fits
----------------------------- [SVR_rbf] ------------------------------
Score:      44.88%
Parameters: {'SVR_rbf__C': 10, 'SVR_rbf__max_iter': 500}
**********************************************************************
---------------------------- [SVR_linear] ----------------------------
Score:      33.40%
Parameters: {'SVR_linear__C': 0.01, 'SVR_linear__max_iter': 1000}
**********************************************************************
------------------------------ [Ridge] -------------------------------
Score:      34.83%
Parameters: {'Ridge__alpha': 500, 'Ridge__max_iter': 200}
**********************************************************************
------------------------------ [Lasso] -------------------------------
Score:      22.90%
Parameters: {'Lasso__alpha': 0.1, 'Lasso__max_iter': 1000}
**********************************************************************
--------------------------- [RandomForest] ---------------------------
Score:      36.87%
Parameters: {'RandomForest__max_depth': 5, 'RandomForest__n_estimators': 250}
**********************************************************************
Mean Squared Error: {'SVR_rbf': 5.375, 'SVR_linear': 7.036, 'Ridge': 7.02, 'Lasso': 8.108, 'RandomForest': 9.475}
```

**Code:**

```
import os
#import contextlib
from operator import itemgetter
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor, Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.externals import joblib


def get_data(path='.'):
    p = Path(path)
    kwargs = dict(delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    X_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    y_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainY.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    X_test = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('testX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    y_test = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('testY.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    return (pd.concat([X_train, X_test], ignore_index=True),
            pd.concat([y_train, y_test], ignore_index=True)[0])


def get_data_split(path='.', test_size=0.25):
    X, y = get_data(path)
    return train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size)


def tune_models_hyperparams(X, y, models, **common_grid_kwargs):
    grids = {}
    for model in models:
        print('{:-^70}'.format(' [' + model['name'] + '] '))
        pipe = Pipeline([
                    ("scale", StandardScaler()),
                    (model['name'], model['model'])   ])
        grids[model['name']] = (GridSearchCV(pipe,
                                           param_grid=model['param_grid'],
                                           **common_grid_kwargs)
                                  .fit(X, y))
        # saving single trained model ...
        joblib.dump(grids[model['name']], './{}.pkl'.format(model['name']))
    return grids


def get_best_model(grid, X_test, y_test,
                        metric_func=mean_squared_error):
    res = {name : round(metric_func(y_test, model.predict(X_test)), 3)
           for name, model in grid.items()}
    print('Mean Squared Error:', res)
    best_model_name = min(res, key=itemgetter(1))
    return grid[best_model_name]


def test_dataset(grid, X_test, y_test):
    res = {}
    for name, model in grid.items():
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
        res[name] = {'MSE': mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred),
                       'R2': r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
                      }
    return res

def predict(grid, X_test, model_name):
    return grid[model_name].predict(X_test)


def print_grid_results(grids):
    for name, model in grids.items():
        print('{:-^70}'.format(' [' + name + '] '))
        print('Score:\t\t{:.2%}'.format(model.best_score_))
        print('Parameters:\t{}'.format(model.best_params_))
        print('*' * 70)


models = [
    {   'name':     'SVR_rbf',
        'model':    SVR(),
        'title':    "SVR_rbf",
        'param_grid': {
            'SVR_rbf__C':           [0.1, 1, 5, 10],
            'SVR_rbf__max_iter':    [500]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'SVR_linear',
        'model':      SVR(kernel='linear'),
        'title':    "SVR_rbf",
        'param_grid': {
            'SVR_linear__C':           [0.01, 0.1, 1, 5],
            'SVR_linear__max_iter':    [1000]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'Ridge',
        'model':    Ridge(),
        'title':    "Ridge",
        'param_grid': {
            'Ridge__alpha':         [0.1, 0.5, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500],
            'Ridge__max_iter':      [200]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'Lasso',
        'model':    Lasso(),
        'title':    "Lasso",
        'param_grid':  {
            'Lasso__alpha':         [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
            'Lasso__max_iter':      [1000]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'RandomForest',
        'model':    RandomForestRegressor(),
        'title':    "RandomForest",
        'param_grid':  {
            'RandomForest__n_estimators':   [50, 250, 500],
            'RandomForest__max_depth':      [5],
        } 
    },
]


def main(path):
    os.chdir(str(path))

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        get_data_split(path, test_size=127/510.)
    grid = tune_models_hyperparams(X_train, y_train, models, cv=3,
                                   verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
    print_grid_results(grid)
    model = get_best_model(grid, X_test, y_test)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'predicted': model.predict(X_test)})
    df.to_csv('predicted.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p =  Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
    main(p)
```

Comment: great job. I will check it when I go to the office. Does split data set work as k-fold validation?

Comment: @Jame, no, it's a simple split - the idea is to shuffle the data and randomly select train and test data sets of approx. the same size... You may want to try a different approaches here...

Comment: Thanks. For the result, could you tell me why your first answer and second answer give a different performance? The first answer looks better

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@George](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094242/svm-provided-a-bad-result-in-my-data-how-to-fix#comment85195254_49094242) - `"there is something "wrong" with the test set"`. I got similar results of MSE - approx. 21.

I also tried to put train and test datasets together and feed it to GridSearchCV.

Here are the results of those attempts:

```
In [33]: print_grid_results(grid)
----------------------------- [SVR_rbf] ------------------------------
Score:          48.98%
Parameters:     {'SVR_rbf__C': 5, 'SVR_rbf__max_iter': 500}
**********************************************************************
---------------------------- [SVR_linear] ----------------------------
Score:          64.07%
Parameters:     {'SVR_linear__C': 0.1, 'SVR_linear__max_iter': 500}
**********************************************************************
------------------------------ [Ridge] -------------------------------
Score:          63.98%
Parameters:     {'Ridge__alpha': 100, 'Ridge__max_iter': 200}
**********************************************************************
------------------------------ [Lasso] -------------------------------
Score:          60.36%
Parameters:     {'Lasso__alpha': 0.001, 'Lasso__max_iter': 1000}
**********************************************************************
--------------------------- [RandomForest] ---------------------------
Score:          44.01%
Parameters:     {'RandomForest__max_depth': 5, 'RandomForest__n_estimators': 100}
**********************************************************************
```

Also different splits are giving very different test scores:

```
In [43]: clf = grid['SVR_linear']

In [44]: {k:v for k,v in clf.cv_results_.items() if k.endswith('_test_score')}
Out[44]:
{'mean_test_score': array([0.64067998, 0.63919104, 0.6391681 , 0.64067998, 0.63919104, 0.6391681 , 0.64067998, 0.63919104, 0.6391681 ]),
 'rank_test_score': array([1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7]),
 'split0_test_score': array([0.98557453, 0.98876705, 0.98883802, 0.98557453, 0.98876705, 0.98883802, 0.98557453, 0.98876705, 0.98883802]),
 'split1_test_score': array([0.69915178, 0.69750946, 0.69740475, 0.69915178, 0.69750946, 0.69740475, 0.69915178, 0.69750946, 0.69740475]),
 'split2_test_score': array([0.23568677, 0.22964765, 0.22961214, 0.23568677, 0.22964765, 0.22961214, 0.23568677, 0.22964765, 0.22961214]),
 'std_test_score': array([0.30903146, 0.31275403, 0.31278954, 0.30903146, 0.31275403, 0.31278954, 0.30903146, 0.31275403, 0.31278954])}
```

Here is a full code:

```
import os
#import contextlib
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor, Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.externals import joblib


def get_data_split(path='.'):
    p = Path(path)
    kwargs = dict(delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    X_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    y_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainY.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    X_test = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('testX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    y_test = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('testY.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    return X_train, y_train[0], X_test, y_test[0]


def get_data(path='.'):
    p = Path(path)
    kwargs = dict(delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    X_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    y_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainY.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    X_test = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('testX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    y_test = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('testY.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
    return (pd.concat([X_train, X_test], ignore_index=True),
            pd.concat([y_train, y_test], ignore_index=True)[0])


def fit_all_classifiers_grid(X, y, classifiers, **common_grid_kwargs):
    grids = {}
    for clf in classifiers:
        print('{:-^70}'.format(' [' + clf['name'] + '] '))
        pipe = Pipeline([
                    ("scale", StandardScaler()),
                    (clf['name'], clf['clf'])   ])
        grids[clf['name']] = (GridSearchCV(pipe,
                                           param_grid=clf['param_grid'],
                                           **common_grid_kwargs)
                                  .fit(X, y))
        # saving single trained model ...
        joblib.dump(grids[clf['name']], './{}.pkl'.format(clf['name']))
    return grids


def test_dataset(grid, X_test, y_test):
    res = {}
    for name, clf in grid.items():
        y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
        res[name] = {'MSE': mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred),
                       'R2': r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
                      }
    return res


def print_grid_results(grids):
    for name, clf in grids.items():
        print('{:-^70}'.format(' [' + name + '] '))
        print('Score:\t\t{:.2%}'.format(clf.best_score_))
        print('Parameters:\t{}'.format(clf.best_params_))
        print('*' * 70)




classifiers = [
    {   'name':     'SVR_rbf',
        'clf':      SVR(),
        'title':    "SVR_rbf",
        'param_grid': {
            'SVR_rbf__C':           [0.1, 1, 5],
            'SVR_rbf__max_iter':    [500, 1000, 5000]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'SVR_linear',
        'clf':      SVR(kernel='linear'),
        'title':    "SVR_rbf",
        'param_grid': {
            'SVR_linear__C':           [0.1, 1, 5],
            'SVR_linear__max_iter':    [500, 1000, 5000]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'Ridge',
        'clf':      Ridge(),
        'title':    "Ridge",
        'param_grid': {
            'Ridge__alpha':         [0.1, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100],
            'Ridge__max_iter':      [200, 500]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'Lasso',
        'clf':      Lasso(),
        'title':    "Lasso",
        'param_grid':  {
            'Lasso__alpha':         [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10],
            'Lasso__max_iter':      [1000, 5000]
        } 
    },
    {   'name':     'RandomForest',
        'clf':      RandomForestRegressor(),
        'title':    "RandomForest",
        'param_grid':  {
            'RandomForest__n_estimators':   [10, 100],
            'RandomForest__max_depth':      [3, 5],
        } 
    },
]


def main(path):
    #path = r'D:\data\work\.ML\SO\49094242-SVM provided a bad result in my data'
    os.chdir(path)

    X, y = get_data(path)
    grid = fit_all_classifiers_grid(X, y, classifiers, cv=3, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
    print_grid_results(grid)

    #X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = get_data_split(path)
    #grid = fit_all_classifiers_grid(X_train, y_train, classifiers, cv=2, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
    #res = test_dataset(grid, X_test, y_test)
    #print(res)
```

PS sorry for using name `classifier` instead of `regressor` - I just reused my old code where I was searching for the best **classifier**....

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you tell me how to achieve prediction on test set with a given searched parameters? I have tried in Ubuntu but I cannot run it with error `X_train = pd.read_csv(list(p.glob('trainX.txt*'))[0], **kwargs)
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Jame, you don't have to use `p.glob()` - you can simply pass there a full file name - i used it this way, because i've GZipped your files and I... didn't want to confuse you with names like `"trainX.txt.gz"` ...

Comment: Thanks. I have ran it successful

Comment: Given an optimal parameter setting (assume achieve from your grid search), could you tell me how to use it to predict in the testing set as my result show in the question?

Comment: @Jame, `grid[classifier_name].predict(X_test)`

Comment: Thanks MaxU. I got the result now when I change the dataset.  In your code, does it save the best model in the file pkl? This is my log `[RandomForest] 
Score:  67.88%
Parameters: {'RandomForest__n_estimators': 100, RandomForest__max_depth': 5}
- [SVR_rbf] -
Score: 81.66% Parameters:{'SVR_rbf__C': 5, 'SVR_rbf__max_iter': 500}
- [Lasso] - Score: 100.00% Parameters: {'Lasso__alpha': 0.001, 'Lasso__max_iter': 1000} - [Ridge] - Score: 100.00%
Parameters: {'Ridge__alpha': 0.1, 'Ridge__max_iter': 200}
-- [SVR_linear] - Score:  99.95%
Parameters:{'SVR_linear__C': 0.1, 'SVR_linear_': 5000}`

Comment: @Jame, yes, all trained models will be saved in corresponding `.pkl` files... What did you change in your data set to get such good scores?

Comment: Sure. Could you tell me how to run the best model of `SVR_linear` with optimal hyperparameters? I was tried `grid[classifier_name].predict(X_test)` but it show error

Comment: @Jame, i can make an example in 5-6 hours when i'll get home... But 100% - looks suspicious - I guess it's overfitting... Can you provide your updated data sets?

Answer (score 0):

according to your dataset it seems that your features are too high. It is better to use features grouping algorithms before you start processing with SVM.

Comment: you can setup scikitfeatureselection from link below and use algorithms that has provided. it contains more than 40algorithms.http://featureselection.asu.edu/

Comment: I have passed the feature selection and it resulted as above feature. I do not think I have to do again