# GridSearchCV not choose the optimal result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, tfidfvectorizer

In my sklearn classification model, when I set the "ngram_range=(4,4)" parameter of TfidfVectorizer manually, I got 0.58 as a result of f1_macro .. and for example for unigram (1,1) the result is 0.49 ..

The problem is, when I used GridSearchCv method to choose the optimal parameter, it didn't give me the optimal parameter but it return the result of the first element in the parameter set, take a look in my code to make it more clear:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, average_precision_score
import re
from os import walk
import csv
import operator

# variables --
co = dict()
lex = []

def tokenizeManu(txt):
    txt = clean_str(txt)
    return txt.split()

def tokenizeTfidf(txt):
    return txt.split() return txt.split() # It just split the text without any operation

def repAllTxt(txt):
    out = re.sub("[a-z]|[A-Z]", '*', txt)
    out = re.sub("[0-9]", '#', out)
    return out

def corpDict(x):
    count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), tokenizer=tokenizeManu, lowercase=False)
    countFit = count.fit_transform(x)
    vocab = count.get_feature_names()
    dist = np.sum(countFit.toarray(), axis=0)
    for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
        co[tag] = count

    # print(len(co))

def clean_str(string):
    string = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9()\-\":.$,!?\'\`]", r" ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"([()\-\":.,!?\'\`])", r" \1 ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'s", r" \'s", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'m", r" \'m", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'ve", r" \'ve", string)
    string = re.sub(r"n\'t", r" n\'t", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'re", r" \'re", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'d", r" \'d", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'ll", r" \'ll", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", r" ", string)
    return string.strip()

def readLexicons():
    path = 'lexicons'
    # Load data from files
    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
        for i in filenames:
            f.append(str(dirpath+'\\'+i))

    lexList = []
    for pa in f:
        if pa.endswith('txt') == True:
            with open(pa, encoding="utf8") as inf:
                reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
                col = list(zip(*reader))
                lexList.extend(col[0])
        else:
            file_object = open(pa, "r")
            file_object = file_object.read()
            file_object = re.findall(r'((?<=word1=)\w+)', file_object)
            lexList.extend(file_object)
    lex.extend(lexList)

def prepTxtStar(X, kValue, maintainLex):
    sorted_co = sorted(co.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:kValue]
    sorted_co = list([i[0] for i in sorted_co])

    for row in range(len(X)):
        c = str(X[row]).split()
        for i in range(len(c)):
            if c[i] in co.keys():
                if not sorted_co.__contains__(c[i]):
                    if maintainLex == 0:
                        c[i] = repAllTxt(c[i])
                    else:
                        if not lex.__contains__(c[i]):
                            c[i] = repAllTxt(c[i])
        X[row] = ' '.join(c)
    for x in X[:3]:
        print(x)
    return X

def readFiles():
    path = 'datasetpaaaaaaaaaaath/ds.txt'

    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
        for i in filenames:
            f.append(str(dirpath+'\\'+i))
    x = []
    y = []
    lexList = []
    for pa in f:
        if pa.endswith('txt') == True:
            with open(pa, encoding="utf8") as inf:
                reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
                col = list(zip(*reader))
                x.extend(col[2])
                y.extend(col[3])
    return x,y





if __name__ == "__main__":
    xOri, yOri = readFiles()
    xOri = [clean_str(i) for i in xOri]
    readLexicons()
    corpDict(xOri)
    xOri = prepTxtStar(xOri, kValue=10000000, maintainLex=0)


    x, xTest, y, yTest = train_test_split(xOri, yOri, test_size=0.32, random_state=42)
    model = Pipeline([
                        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer( analyzer='char_wb', min_df=0.0007,lowercase=False,tokenizer=tokenizeTfidf)),
                        ('clf', SGDClassifier(tol=None, loss='hinge', random_state=38, max_iter=5))
                     ])

    # Grid search
    parameters = {
                    'tfidf__ngram_range': [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)]
                 }
    gs_clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1_macro')
    gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(x, y)

    predicted = gs_clf.predict(xTest)
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print("%s: %r" % (param_name, gs_clf.best_params_[param_name]))
    print('F1 Macro: ', f1_score(yTest, predicted, average='macro'))
```

In this example, I got the following results:

```
tfidf__ngram_range: (1, 1)
F1 Macro:  0.4927875243664717
```

So, it choose the first element of the parameter set (1,1) while the best one according to f1_score is (4,4) !

what is the problem, did i miss something?

Editted: The full source code is added with the dataset: [Dataset](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8tdb7p9hjfom7x1/ds.txt)

Comment: can you provide or share your data sets?

Comment: @MaxU , I updated the code ..

Comment: thank you! Could you please shortly explain the meaning of those four columns?

Comment: Line number, the speaker,  the text, label (0 as opinion, 1 as a fact)

Comment: OK, let me try to play with this data set. I'll post an answer if will get a better score... ;-)

Comment: I'm waiting .. yes there are better results but I wrote is just an example for ngram case

Comment: Can you please show the code in which you are getting the score of 0.58. On what data are you calculating that? GridsearchCV will split the supplied data into train test and then calculate the average of 3-fold validation scores. Surely you are not doing that on your calculations.

Comment: @VivekKumar, Every thing in the code ,, download the dataset and run the code ..

Comment: In the above code I only see the grid-search based code. Where have you calculated the score for (4,4) ngram here?

Comment: before the GS with 5 lines you will find it .. in the Pipeline ..

Comment: No, still cant see it in your posted code here.

Comment: Refresh the page, Ctrl+F5, cause I updated the code ..

Comment: The last edit is shown as 11 hours ago. Please take a look.

Comment: screen capture image: https://ibb.co/fz1EHx

Comment: Thats not that. There you are just defining the model. Where are you getting the score 0.58? Please post that code.

Comment: Delete the GS part and fit the pipleline like here: pipeline.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['label'])
    predicted = pipeline.predict(test_df['text']) , and add ngram_range=(4,4) as a parameter for TfidfVectorizer ..

Comment: Thats what I was asking. Refer to my first comment carefully. For finding the best-params, grid-search will not use the whole dataset. It will cross-validate on the data for each param and get the param which gave the best mean score on the data. That may (mostly will) not match the results when used on full data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167412/discussion-between-mib-minion-and-vivek-kumar).

Comment: See [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49165571/3374996) and also see the linked answers there.

Comment: Ok its clear now ..